How to call an api from Share Point (Subscription Edition) event receiver with impersonation?
I am very new to Share Point development.
I am trying call an api from ItemUpdating event as follows -
        public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            var postData = new
            {
                itemCode = "itemCode",
                data = "data",
            };
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData.ToString());
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
            {
                using (var client = new WebClient { UseDefaultCredentials = true })
                {
                    client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    var returnData = client.UploadData("http://api.domain.org/Submit", "POST", data);
                }
            });
        }

Sharepoint server and api hosting server are in windows environment using windows and kerberos authentication. Delegation is set properly from Sharepoint server app pool identity to api hosting server spn.
With this code api receives Sharepoint app pool user identity. We want to receive the originating user's identity in API.
Would that be possible? If yes how?
